# How use select2 with knockout arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, knockout.js, jquery-select2

I got this array:

```
self.Tags() = ko.observableArray();

$.getJSON("/myService/GetAllTags", "projectid=" + tp.ProjectId,
            function (allData) {
                var mappedTags = $.map(allData, function (item) {
                    return new Tag(item)
                });

    self.Tags(mappedTags);
}
```

where

```
Tag = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.tagId = data.TagId;     
    self.projectId = data.TagProjectId;
    self.textbatchId = data.TagTextbatchId;
    self.text = ko.observable(data.TagName);
    self.tagType = ko.observable(data.TagType);
};
```

This is my select2 HTML:

```
<input data-bind="value: myTags, select2Value: selectedTags, select2: { tags: ko.toJS($root.Tags), minimumInputLength: 1, tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']}" />
```

myTags and selectedTags are derived from Tags with filtering and mapping.

The projectId, textbatchId and tagType are data I need. 
However I cannot get the select2 input to accept these values in an array.
Neither can I get select2 to accept tagId and other data-indicated different than "id" and "text".

Is there any way I can tell select2 to use tagId as "id" and to ignore the rest of the attributes?

I know the select2 man pages probably say something about this, but I cannot get my head around it.
Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vJqQy/2/

Comment: Your first code line "self.Tags() = ko.observableArray();" is invalid, but I guess that's just a typo from creating the question on SO. Could you create a jsfiddle (or use similar service) which shows your problem, and of course explain what you want the fiddle to do? That would make it easier to assist you, for those of us who are not familiar with Select2 and whatever Select2 bindingHandlers you're using.

Comment: Thanx @robert.westerlund ! I have created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vJqQy/2/

See if you understand what I mean. I am quite surprised what I want is so hard to achieve as it should be rather basic use with tagging. Then again, it´s probably my lack of understanding that makes it complex. ;)

Comment: Do I understand the comments in your fiddle correctly if I understand that you want the Select2-list to be prepopulated with all items in the Tags-list with a specific batch id? And the problem being that you can't get the initial selection to work?

Comment: @robert.westerlund I have created a new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vKbmn/1/

My problem here is that "myManagers" does´t update when I remove already set tags. (click the x´s and you´ll see).

Comment: You're never ever changing the value of the observable myManagers. You're replacing the whole observable, but never the observed object. However, your fiddle has a lot of code and markup not at all related to your question. Also, the fiddle you refer to seems to have very little to do with the original question. Is the original question solved? Please make new questions for... well new questions and try to keep each question with a single purpose. Fiddles and samples for a question should preferably show only the issue at hand, to make it easier to assist you.